# How to achieve multiple orderByChild queries in Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I know that firebase does not allow multiple orderByChild query, so twe have to restructure the code to achieve the same effect. I am trying, but I am stuck on how to do so.

I have the following database structure:

```
posts: {
   "-LY0tr3NmAlZhJDfxMch": {
   "State": "California",
   "City": "SanFrancisco",
   "StateCity": "California_SanFrancisco",
   "createdAt": 1549441397199,
   "postText": "Hello!!",
   "starCount": 0,
   "userId": "blAWQ9g9YMciB312fasdawqeqw",
   },
....
}
```

What I wish to do is view the posts queried with State and/or City, **as well as** order them by starCount. Just viewing the posts based on the State and/or City can be done by using the following.

```
 firebase
        .database()
        .ref()
        .child("posts")
        .orderByChild("State") // or City or StateCity
        .equalTo('...')
        ...
```

Above would return me all the posts only based on State or City or StateCity. 
Now what I wish to do is order these returned query again with number of starCount. For example, the follows:

```
 firebase
        .database()
        .ref()
        .child("posts")
        .orderByChild("State") // or City or StateCity
        .equalTo('e.g. California') // query posts that have state California
        .orderByChild("StarCount") // from posts of California, order them by starCount
        .once("value")
        ...
```

I cannot use orderByChild again, so I'm stuck on how I might be able to restructure my database to achieve the above result.

How may I do so? Thank you !

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: im using javacript client side. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your question, you can't do it, Firebase doesn't allow it.
You need to get the results from the first query, and order them by code AFTER the once("value") call.

```
var stateResult = firebase.database()
        .ref()
        .child("posts")
        .orderByChild("State") // 
        .equalTo('...');

//Do something here with the returned stateResult to order them by StarCount
```

You don't need to restructure your database for that, just do it in code

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea how to start to order the returned values with starcount in the code?